# Remap Caps Lock and Preserve Original Function

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, caps-lock

I know I can remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Escape</kbd>. However, sometimes I do actually want to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. Is there a way to achieve this, for example by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>?

Comment: The problem that you've run into is that `Fn` is not "mappable" since it's not sent.  It modifies the keys internally to the keyboard and not programmable.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `Fn`. It could be any key like `Option` + `Caps Lock`